# Hadoop Streaming Hangs at Output: /path../output

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

Hi I wrote myself two scripts in Python as the mapper and reducer for Hadoop Streaming. I run the code and it successfully finished the mapping and reducing, both 100%. But it just hung there at the end of the process.

output looks like this:

```
...
13/10/07 17:25:16 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 99%  reduce 30%
13/10/07 17:26:18 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 99%  reduce 31%
13/10/07 17:26:55 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 99%  reduce 32%
13/10/07 17:28:16 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 32%
13/10/07 17:29:08 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 33%
13/10/07 17:30:55 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 39%
13/10/07 17:30:56 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 46%
13/10/07 17:30:57 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 52%
13/10/07 17:30:58 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 72%
13/10/07 17:31:00 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 74%
13/10/07 17:31:01 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 89%
13/10/07 17:31:02 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 98%
13/10/07 17:31:03 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 99%
13/10/07 17:31:57 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 100%
13/10/07 17:32:00 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Job complete: job_201309301959_0100
13/10/07 17:32:00 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Output: /tmp/binwang_31
```

Our cluster is monitored by ganglia and I can clearly see all the nodes came back to normal and not doing heavy calculating. Meanwhile, I went to hdfs and can find my output sitting there. (Not sure complete or not). To me it seems like the whole map reduce has finished successfully but the terminal hangs at the last step for more than 10 minutes...

I am wondering how could this happen and should I CTRL+Z to stop it or give another few minutes to go. Anyone knows whether the output:... step should take that much long time? 
If not, what might be the reason?

[image]

Here is the response when I opened up another session and run the command

```
$ /usr/bin/hadoop job -status job_201309301959_0100
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute mapred command is deprecated.
Instead use the mapred command for it.


Job: job_201309301959_0100
file: hdfs://url1:8020/user/user1/.staging/job_201309301959_0100/job.xml
tracking URL: http://url1:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201309301959_0100
map() completion: 1.0
reduce() completion: 1.0
Counters: 34
    File System Counters
            FILE: Number of bytes read=232427562
            FILE: Number of bytes written=835363817
            FILE: Number of read operations=0
            FILE: Number of large read operations=0
            FILE: Number of write operations=0
            HDFS: Number of bytes read=107873895369
            HDFS: Number of bytes written=51760077
            HDFS: Number of read operations=1722
            HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
            HDFS: Number of write operations=144
    Job Counters
            Launched map tasks=803
            Launched reduce tasks=72
            Data-local map tasks=731
            Rack-local map tasks=72
            Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=521490905
            Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=47701745
            Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
            Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
            Map input records=425093
            Map output records=10311822
            Map output bytes=906412336
            Input split bytes=111617
            Combine input records=0
            Combine output records=0
            Reduce input groups=550636
            Reduce shuffle bytes=452246236
            Reduce input records=10311822
            Reduce output records=550636
            Spilled Records=20623644
            CPU time spent (ms)=479770510
            Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=533152505856
            Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=1439405166592
            Total committed heap usage (bytes)=844896337920
    org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormatCounter
            BYTES_READ=107742318536
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: showing the code you wrote for mapper and reducer will help us to help you.

Comment: sorry, the code is too long to upload 200+ lines of code. The purpose of the mapper is basically parse html and print <key:productName, value:inventory, price, timestamp>, the reducer does some time series analysis. Do you think based on the content in the picture, I can say the job has actually already finished?

Comment: The output is incomplete; you are missing the last two lines; the last one should say `BYTES_WRITTEN...`. Perhaps something happened that made the job hang. You could try running it again and see if it finishes without problems.